# Ubuntu 12.04 with Nvidia 304.88 GT 220 not keeping resolution wwhen switching inputs HDMI on HDTV

Tags: 12.04, gnome, nvidia, resolution, hdmi

Strange problem since the latest 'upgrade' for the Nvidia drivers (to 304.88).

My HTPC - Ubuntu 12.04 - is connected to my HDTV via a Samsung receiver. This receiver does all the switching for my HDMI connected devices (PS3, DVD, Satellite box, etc).

Before the Nvidia update, I had no problem switching between devices and back to the HTPC. However, now when I do this, the resolution on the HTPC changes from my preferred setting (1360 x 768) to "Auto" (which is 1920 x 1080).

I am running Gnome Shell 3.4. I have checked this in Unity and xfce and Gnome Classic, all with the same results.

Similar problem as this year old question, but I get video - https://askubuntu.com/questions/132769/no-video-on-an-nvidia-geforce-gt-440-when-switching-from-another-hdmi-device

Comment: I'll give that a try.

Additional info - since the 304.88 update, the video (visually) is bad...grainy almost. Not the TV, as everything else is fine, just the computer...on every setting I have tried.

Comment: Sorta, kinda figured it out. Tried to purge Nvidia and use Nouveau instead, but Nvidia just kept on reinstalling during reboot. So I tried different resolutions and found one that sticks and works well (1280x720). At least things are not so tiny that I can't read them! Thanks for everyone's help!!

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but I'm forcing the resolution in xorg.conf with a modeline for my TV (specifically: Modeline "1280x720"   74.25  1280 1390 1430 1650  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync) so this is the only resolution that my xserver should be supporting. I don't have a kb or mouse hooked up so my only recourse is to reboot the box via ssh. Time to file a bug?